# Gardening to help protect a toddler

Tags: shrubs

We have a flat in England with a very active toddler and a balcony shared between the neighbours.  We're trying to grow something at the edges of 'our' bit of the blacony to protect the nighbours privacy.  Looking for any advice on a plant/ bush/ shrubbery which is:

1. Resilient to both summer heat and winter drizzle
2. Can survive in pretty limited soil (we have a dozen 6" deep plant pots)
3. Grows to a density/thickness where a toddler can't penetrate it.
4. And does this all pretty quickly.

Appreciate if we are after the unobtanium of plant matter!

Cheers for any help.

Comment: You may have to buy a well grown plant. Or perhaps fasten a trelis there first. Then pot a plant that you would like to look at

Comment: How wide is the balcony?

Comment: Six inch pots are too small to grow a dense, evergreen shrub properly, but we need more info - how long and wide is the balcony; what's the aspect, or which way does it face; is there a roof over the balcony;   does it receive full or very little sun; how exposed to wind is it and so  on... a photo or two of the area would be helpful